# Applying merge policies when merging features in same layer using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, fields-attributes, road, domains

I am trying to figure out how to merge line features within the same feature class such that particular fields will be summed. For example, in the following picture I have two lines that I wish to sum the "TRVLTIM" or travel time field, such that the merged line has a value of 0.055737.

[image]

I have tried setting up a domain with the "Merge Policy" set to "Sum Values" and applying it to this field, but as described on the following [ArcGIS help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/merging-features-in-the-same-layer.htm), the "Merge" button in the editor toolbar ignores merge policies.

Is it possible to prevent the editor merge tool from ignoring domains?

I want to repeat this process for several roads. I am aware that geoprocessing tools exist that can perform this sum, but it would be impractical to recreate this massive roadway feature class every time I want to merge.

Answer (score 1):

You can [Dissolve tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/h-how-dissolve-data-management-works.htm#GUID-94A37BAB-D43B-45A3-9F1E-288073C640E9) to merge the lines with same IDs and use Statistical Field to sum the lines merged together. The Dissolve tool located in `ArcToolbox -> Data Management Tools -> Generalization -> Dissolve`

In the following Sample, I have lines with two fields: `id` and `TT`.

[image]

I dissolved the lines based on `id` field and I added the `TT` under Statistical Field and used `SUM` to sum all values under TT field.

[image]

The output will be merged lines with summed `TT` values

[image]